# Why is my kafkaproducer not sending the apropriate message? "personResource is null. Cannot send the message to Kafka"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, quarkus, kafka-producer-api

I'm completely new to Kafka and i have some troubles using the KafkaProducer. Even though I'm using the same logic of a previous more simple project it seems as the class with emitter is going null and so it doesn't send any message though the message I need sent is correct.

How can I solve this?

---

My project:

---

PersonEntity:

```
package org.acme.Entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import jakarta.persistence.Embedded;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(name = "KafkaWorkerService")
public class PersonEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Embedded
    private Name name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Embeddable
    public static class Name {

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @XmlTransient
        private String first;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @XmlTransient
        private String last;
    }
}
```

MyRouteBuilder:

```
package org.acme.Routes;

import org.acme.Processors.JsonProcessor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private final String inputDirectory = "C:\\Users\\william.santos\\Desktop\\IntegrationTest\\Input\\";
    private final String outputDirectory = "C:\\Users\\william.santos\\Desktop\\IntegrationTest\\Output\\";
    
    boolean isJson = true;
    

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        

        from("file:" + inputDirectory + "?maxMessagesPerPoll=1")
            .choice()
                .when(header("CamelFileName").endsWith(".json"))
                    .process(new JsonProcessor())
                .otherwise()**/
                    .log("Unsupported file type")
            .end()
                .to("file:" + outputDirectory);
    }
}
```

JsonProcessor:

```
package org.acme.Processors;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.acme.Entities.PersonEntity;
import org.acme.Resources.PersonResource;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named("jsonProcessor")
public class JsonProcessor implements Processor {

    @Inject
    @Named("personResource")
    PersonResource personResource;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        // Extract JSON data from the exchange
        String json = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

        // Deserialize the JSON data into a PersonEntity array
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.addMixIn(PersonEntity.class, IgnoreIdMixin.class);
        PersonEntity[] personEntities = objectMapper.readValue(json, PersonEntity[].class);

        // List to hold all entities
        List<PersonEntity> allEntities = new ArrayList<>();

        // Extract the fields you need from the PersonEntity objects and add them to a
        // list
        for (PersonEntity personEntity : personEntities) {
            allEntities.add(personEntity);
        }

        // Send each entity to Kafka one at a time
        for (PersonEntity personEntity : allEntities) {
            // Extract the fields from the current PersonEntity
            String name = personEntity.getName().getFirst() + " " + personEntity.getName().getLast();
            String age = personEntity.getAge().toString();
            String email = personEntity.getEmail();

            // Create a message for the current person
            String[] fields = { name, age, email };

            String message = String.join(", ", fields);

            System.out.println("Message to send: " + message);

            // Send the message to Kafka
            // Send the message to Kafka
            if (personResource != null) {
                personResource.sendPerson(message);
            } else {
                // Handle the case when personResource is null
                System.out.println("personResource is null. Cannot send the message to Kafka.");
            }
            // Wait for the acknowledgement or confirmation of the previous message
            waitForPreviousMessageToBeSent();
        }
    }

    // Mixin class to ignore the "id" field during deserialization
    private static abstract class IgnoreIdMixin {
        @JsonIgnore
        private Long id;
    }

    private void waitForPreviousMessageToBeSent() throws InterruptedException {
        // You can implement your own mechanism here to wait for the previous message to
        // be sent.
        // This can be done using synchronization, a queue, or any other suitable
        // approach.
        // For demonstration purposes, let's add a sleep of 1 second as a simple way to
        // simulate the wait.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

PersonResource:

```
package org.acme.Resources;

import org.acme.Processors.JsonProcessor;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Channel;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named("personResource")
@Path("/person")
public class PersonResource {

    @Inject
    @Named("jsonProcessor")
    JsonProcessor jsonProcessor;

    /**
     * @Inject @Named("xmlProcessor") XmlProcessor xmlProcessor;
     **/

    @Inject
    @Channel("person-out")
    Emitter<String> kafkaEmitter;

    @POST
    @Path("/send-person")
    public Response sendPerson(String message) {
        try {
            
            kafkaEmitter.send(message);
            System.out.println("Message sent: " + message);

            ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
            return builder.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage())
                    .build();
        }
    }

}
```

getting the following:

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m---------------------< [0;36morg.acme:code-with-quarkus[0;1m >---------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mquarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.2.Final:dev[m [1m(default-cli)[m @ [36mcode-with-quarkus[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources @ code-with-quarkus
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] Copying 3 resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] Invoking io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.2.Final:generate-code @ code-with-quarkus
[[1;34mINFO[m] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile @ code-with-quarkus
[[1;34mINFO[m] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[[1;34mINFO[m] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources @ code-with-quarkus
[[1;34mINFO[m] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[[1;34mINFO[m] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\william.santos\Desktop\Quarkus\Quarkus-Integration-Exercise\src\test\resources
[[1;34mINFO[m] Invoking io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.2.Final:generate-code-tests @ code-with-quarkus
[[1;34mINFO[m] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile @ code-with-quarkus
[[1;34mINFO[m] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Press [h] for more options>
Tests paused
Press [r] to resume testing, [h] for more options>
Press [r] to resume testing, [o] Toggle test output, [h] for more options>
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2023-05-15 13:19:58,889 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.CamelBootstrapRecorder] (Quarkus Main Thread) Bootstrap runtime: org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime
2023-05-15 13:19:58,895 INFO  [org.apa.cam.mai.MainSupport] (Quarkus Main Thread) Apache Camel (Main) 4.0.0-M2 is starting
2023-05-15 13:19:59,067 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Apache Camel 4.0.0-M2 (camel-1) is starting
2023-05-15 13:19:59,085 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Routes startup (started:1)
2023-05-15 13:19:59,086 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread)     Started route1 (file://C:%5CUsers%5Cwilliam.santos%5CDesktop%5CIntegrationTest%5CInput%5C)
2023-05-15 13:19:59,086 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Apache Camel 4.0.0-M2 (camel-1) started in 109ms (build:0ms init:91ms start:18ms)
2023-05-15 13:19:59,162 INFO  [io.sma.rea.mes.kafka] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG18229: Configured topics for channel 'person-in': [first_kafka_topic]
2023-05-15 13:19:59,177 INFO  [io.sma.rea.mes.kafka] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG18214: Key deserializer omitted, using String as default
2023-05-15 13:19:59,293 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.com.sec.aut.AbstractLogin] (smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0) Successfully logged in.
2023-05-15 13:19:59,411 INFO  [io.sma.rea.mes.kafka] (smallrye-kafka-producer-thread-0) SRMSG18258: Kafka producer kafka-producer-person-out, connected to Kafka brokers '192.168.1.95:9092', is configured to write records to 'first_kafka_topic'
2023-05-15 13:19:59,422 WARN  [io.sma.rea.mes.provider] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG00208: The connector 'IncomingConnector{channel:'person-in', attribute:'mp.messaging.incoming.person-in'}' has no downstreams
2023-05-15 13:19:59,423 WARN  [io.sma.rea.mes.provider] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG00207: Some components are not connected to either downstream consumers or upstream producers:
    - IncomingConnector{channel:'person-in', attribute:'mp.messaging.incoming.person-in'} has no downstream

2023-05-15 13:19:59,586 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) code-with-quarkus 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.0.2.Final) started in 6.080s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2023-05-15 13:19:59,587 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2023-05-15 13:19:59,587 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [agroal, camel-core, camel-file, camel-sql, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, jdbc-postgresql, kafka-client, narayana-jta, resteasy-reactive, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka, vertx]
Message to send: John Doe, 25, johndoe0125@gmail.com
personResource is null. Cannot send the message to Kafka.
Message to send: Paul Johnson, 29, Paul229Johnson@gmail.com
personResource is null. Cannot send the message to Kafka.
2023-05-15 13:20:06,673 INFO  [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - file://C:%5CUsers%5Cwilliam.santos%5CDesktop%5CIntegrationTest%5CInput%5C) Unsupported file type
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The code is a bit confusing. First, the log complains about a `person-in` channel not consumed by anyone. Then, the log is confusing in the sense it seems that the channel `person-out` is consumed somewhere, but I can't see where. Can you provide the full code, or clean up the question?  The best might be a github repo.